# Merge shapefiles with different divisions

Tags: data, attribute-joins

I have two shapefiles with similar borders but different internal divisions. One shapefiles shows schools' catchment areas and I have a field "mobility". In the other shapefile, there are Census subdivisions and I have unemployment. Y want the unemployment data corresponding to the school's catchment area to be incorporated in the attribute Table of schools. I used "Join Attribute by location" and got something, but the numbers for "unemployment" are repeated in different divisions. Is there any way to overlay the divisions and make an estimate of the unemployment rate according to the geography of that division?

[image: schools]

[image: unemployment]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found as a partial solution. I have a third shapefile (points) with the location of schools. I loaded the points onto the census subdivision shapefile and assigned each school that lay on the division the same unemployment rate. In this way, I have the schools' names with their corresponding unemployment rate. Next, I "joined attributes by location" (the points shapefile into the census subdivision) and thus, I obtained the average unemployment rate fro each school's catchment area. It is not perfect, but I can work a regression now with many other variables in the same attribute table...